# SOLR: how to find result when search term is concatenation of two terms

Tags: solr

I have SOLR running and I can get rsults in case of a partial word search

eg. if user searches "**micro**" I CAN find "**microsoft**"

but If I search for "**microsoftx**" I CANNOT get back "microsoft"

what kind of rules do i have to setup in my schema file?

PS. I have little to zero knowledge of SOLR, I literally installed yesterday.

Comment: Full text search also resolves your question. May this link help you 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731423/what-solr-tokenizer-and-filters-can-i-use-for-a-strong-general-site-search]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by adding an [EdgeNgramFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) to [your analysis chain for the query part](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analyzers). It'll generate tokens for each part of the original word, giving you a search for `micro, micros, microso, microsof, microsoft, microsoftx` for `microsoftx`, depending on how you configure it (`minGramSize`).

Comment: This answer give me a very good explanation about what is the usage of n-gram analysis. Thank you